# listview in windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

am working in windows application with c#.Am creating the listview items dynamically..i want to add columns and items  for the listview and i did it too..i can create items but i cant add the columns name...my code is;

```
private void list_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Columns.Add("id",40, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("name", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("price", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
        listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(textBox2.Text);
        listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(textBox3.Text);

        listView1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text);
        listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(textBox1.Text);
        listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(textBox2.Text);

        listView1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);
        listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(textBox1.Text);
        listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(textBox3.Text);
    }
```

Comment: post the code in a proper way, only half of the code is displaying here.

Comment: both of the answers below are right..two different methods to get this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the ListView property window you have to set up "Details"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create columns statically in Design Mode in UI editor or in other case you can do it on windows load event:

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Columns.Add("id");
        listView1.Columns.Add("name");
        listView1.Columns.Add("price");
   }
```